# How to customize \autoref for a list created with \newlist?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumitem

The desired outcome is marked 'WANTED' in the code below.

PS: [doc](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlist{problem}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[problem]{
  resume,
  label=\emph{\arabic*)}
}

\newcommand{\problemautorefname}{Problem} 

\begin{document}

Problems:
\begin{problem}
\item \lipsum[1][1]\label{pb:foo}
\end{problem}
We solve \autoref{pb:foo}, \dots% WANTED: Problem~1

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Partial solution: `\renewcommand{\itemautorefname}{Problem}`. Useful only if you do not need to refer to normal items with `\autoref`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you use `cleveref`, not `hyperref`, to create the cross-references. The main reason for my recommendation is that `\cref` and `\Cref` let you create cross-references to more than one item at a time.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newlist{problem}{enumerate*}{1} % creates a counter called 'problemi'
\setlist[problem]{resume,left=0pt,
                  label=\emph{\arabic*)},
                  ref=\textup{\arabic*)}}
\crefname{problemi}{problem}{problems}

\begin{document}
Problems:

\begin{problem}
\item\label{pb:foo} \lipsum[1][1]
\item\label{pb:bar} \lipsum[1][2]
\end{problem}

\cref{pb:foo,pb:bar}

\Cref{pb:foo,pb:bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you figure out `problemi`?

Comment: @Erwann - Please check out section 7, "Cloning the basic lists", of the [user guide](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) of the `enumitem` package.